# Intent filter with file scheme and pathPattern wrongly evaluates true

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm using the intent filter below to associate an activity with three types of custom extensions for a "file" scheme: .smmx, .smmstyle and .mm

```
<activity blablabla>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.smmx"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.mm"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.smmstyle"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Problem is, that when used with the dropbox app, this intent filter associates the activity with virtually any extension. For example: when opening files with extensions *.mpb, *.adu - and a lot more - the dropbox app starts the associated activity although there is no match in the filename for any of the above pathPatterns in the intent filter.
It seems the intent filter wrongly evaluates true.

Any idea what might be causing this and how to avoid getting associated with files not intended for my activity?

After adding android:host="*" to each data section, the behaviour changes indeed.
The activity is no longer associated with all extensions. However, now it not always evaluates as matching.
For example this Uri is not matched
file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/Bright%20Orange%20Levels.smmstyle

Although another file with the same extension opened from the same drobox app was matched OK.
This is happening on both a Galaxy GT-I9000 running android 2.2 and Archos 80 G9 running android 3.2
So: much better but not yet perfect. Will research further.

Comment: Try also adding the `android:host` attribute.

Comment: Yes, improves behaviour a lot, but still not perfect. See my changed question above (I don't know if this is how I am supposed to react?)

Comment: Did you try different **android:mimeType** options?

Answer (score 0):

When Android perform matching test between intent and intent-filter, the test for  only compares the URI and the data type in the Intent object to a URI and data type specified in the filter. 
You can see the detail explanation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the documentation, but that does not help.